# Save image from xcode playground to resources folder in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uikit, core-image

How would one programmatically save an image generated from a playground to the resources folder?

I have generated some photos through filters in my playground that I would like to save somehow. The resources folder seems like a good fit. What if I wanted to save the image to the desktop?

I've seen this done with saving images for apps, but I just want to save it to my desktop (or a specified folder in a specified location.)

Comment: Try take a look at Leo Dabus' answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538375/read-file-in-swift-ios-playground#26540934

Comment: that didn't really help that much, can you elaborate? I'd just like to save a .png image to an arbitrary location (like the desktop, for example).

Comment: Did you find how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Create folder first in 'Documents' with name 'Shared Playground Data' otherwise app will give error.

SWIFT 5:

```
let image = // your UIImage
let filepath = playgroundSharedDataDirectory.appendingPathComponent("export.jpg")
let imagedata = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
try! imagedata?.write(to: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: filepath.path))
print("write to \(filepath)")
```

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 11, the folder is not in `~/Documents` anymore for iOS playgrounds but buried deep in `~/Library/Developer/`. You have to print the path and create the `Shared Playground Data` folder manually to save a file from a playground:

```swift
import PlaygroundSupport

// ...
let url = playgroundSharedDataDirectory.appendingPathComponent("example.png")
print(url)
try! image.pngData()!.write(to: url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to save it to the shared data directory:

Create a path to the image:

```
let path = XCPlaygroundSharedDataDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("export.jpg")!
```

(you may need to create the directory `~/Documents/Shared Playground Data/`)

Then to save your output (in this case a CIImage from a filter)

```
let temp:CGImage = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent)!
let image = UIImage(cgImage: temp)
let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
try! data?.write(to: path)
```

Comment: Remember to import XCPlayground

Answer (score 1):

While the first answer helped point me in the right direction, the lack of ability to validate the required `playgroundSharedDataDirectory` path exists, the requirement to create that directory in order for the path to work, as well as force unwrapping (using `!`) the `try` can lead to frustration as well as drag out the process.

Here is a safer, more convenient solution that checks the name you provide for extra safety:

```
func writeImage(_ image: UIImage, name: String) {
    if name.isEmpty || name.count < 3 {
        print("Name cannot be empty or less than 3 characters.")
        return
    }
    guard let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
        print("No documents directory found.")
        return
    }
    let imagePath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(name).png")
    let imagedata = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
    do {
        try imagedata?.write(to: imagePath)
        print("Image successfully written to path:\n\n \(documentsDirectory) \n\n")
    } catch {
        print("Error writing image: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Call using:

```swift
writeImage(image, name: "MyNewImage")
```

A break down of what is happening:

1. The method `writeImage` checks to see if the documents directory exists.
2. If the documents directory does not exist (unlikely), stop process.
3. If the documents directory exists, carry on and write the image to the path.

Comment: Works perfectly fine, but you use image.jpegData, but the image is saved as '.png'

Comment: Good catch @Erik