# print without newline in swift

Tags: swift, swift3, swift2

In swift 2.0, `print()` automatically adds a newline character. In swift 1.2, `println()` and `print()` used to be separate functions. So how do I print some text and not add a newline to it since swift no longer has a print function that does not append newlines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print to console using swift playground?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003092/how-to-print-to-console-using-swift-playground)

Comment: @DánielNagy It is not a duplicate because swift 2.0 does not have a println function. I am not asking how to print to console because print function will do that. I am asking "How to print to console without the newline appended to input text"

Comment: This is explicitly documented in the Xcode 7 beta release notes: *"println and print have been merged together into a single print function with a default argument ..."*

Answer (score 272, accepted):

Starting in Swift 2.0, the recommended method of printing without newline is:

```
print("Hello", terminator: "")
```

Comment: Even though you only see the interface with the `seperator` parameter. You can simply ignore it because it has a default value `func print(items: Any..., separator: String = default, terminator: String = default)`

Comment: Where in the Swift docs  would someone find out what `default` is equal to?

Comment: @7stud `default` is a placeholder for a default value. Ideally, the documentation should contain the actual value, not a placeholder.

Comment: Default values are : separator " "(single space) and terminator \n(new line)

Answer (score 75):

`print` function has changed completely since the late revision of **Swift**, now it looks much simpler and there are variant of method to print to standard console.

The method signature for print looks something like this,

```
public func print<Target>(_ items: Any..., separator: String = default, terminator: String = default, to output: inout Target) where Target : TextOutputStream
```

And here are some usecases,

```
print("Swift is awesome.")
print("Swift", "is", "awesome", separator:" ")
print("Swift", "is", "awesome", separator:" ", terminator:".")
```

Prints:

```
Swift is awesome.
Swift is awesome
Swift is awesome.
```

**Concatenating**

```
print("This is wild", terminator: " ")
print("world")
```

Prints:

```
This is wild world
```

So, using terminator, you should be careful that the contents are relevant to same line.

**Printing Object with *CustomStringConvertible***

```
struct Address {
  let city: String
}

class Person {
  let name = "Jack"
  let addresses = [
    Address(city: "Helsinki"),
    Address(city: "Tampere")
  ]
}

extension Person: CustomStringConvertible {
  var description: String {
    let objectAddress = unsafeBitCast(self, to: Int.self)
    return String(format: "<name: \(name) %p>", objectAddress)
  }
}

let jack = Person()
print(jack)
```

Prints:

```
<name: Jack 0x608000041c20>
```

***CustomDebugStringConvertible***

```
extension Person: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
  var debugDescription: String {
    let objectAddress = unsafeBitCast(self, to: Int.self)

    let addressString = addresses.map { $0.city }.joined(separator: ",")
    return String(format: "<name: \(name), addresses: \(addressString) %p>",objectAddress)
  }
}
```

Now, with **lldb**, you can use **po**  command and it will print object as this in lldb console,

```
<name: Jack, addresses: Helsinki,Tampere 0x60c000044860>
```

**Logging to file using *TextOutputStream***

```
struct MyStreamer: TextOutputStream {

  lazy var fileHandle: FileHandle? = {
    let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: self.logPath)
    return fileHandle
  }()

  var logPath: String = "My file path"

  mutating func write(_ string: String) {
    fileHandle?.seekToEndOfFile()
    fileHandle?.write(string.data(using:.utf8)!)
  }
}
```

Now, using print to stream,

```
print("First of all", to: &myStream )
print("Then after", to: &myStream)
print("And, finally", to: &myStream)
```

Prints to file:

```
First of all
Then after
And finally
```

***CustomReflectable***

```
extension Person: CustomReflectable {
  var customMirror: Mirror {
    return Mirror(self, children: ["name": name, "address1": addresses[0], "address2": addresses[1]])
  }
}
```

Now, in lldb debugger, if you use command po,

```
> po person
```

Result would be something like this,

```
▿ <name: Jack, addresses: Tampere Helsinki  0x7feb82f26e80>
  - name : "Jack"
  ▿ address1 : Address
    - city : "Helsinki"
  ▿ address2 : Address
    - city : "Tampere"
```

Comment: Also not working for me in Xcode 7beta4. Calling `print("foo", appendNewLine: false)` compiles but the output is `(foo), false` and a new line is appended anyway!

Comment: @mluisbrown it's `appendNewline` (lower case `l`)

Answer (score 11):

In Swift 2.0 you can do this:

**Basic version**

```
print("Hello World")
result "Hello World\n"
```

**Using terminator**

```
print("Hello World", terminator:"")
result "Hello World"
```

**Using separator**

```
print("Hello", "World", separator:" ")
result "Hello World\n"
```

**Using separator and terminator**

```
print("Hello", "World", separator:" ", terminator:"")
result "Hello World"
```

**Using one variable**

```
var helloworld = "Hello World"
print(helloworld)
result "Hello World\n"
```

**Using two variables**

```
var hello = "Hello"
var world = "World"
print (hello, world)
result "Hello World\n"
```

Comment: By default the separator is a space `" "`

Answer (score 4):

If you want same line in loop:

```
for i in 1...4
{
    print("", i, separator: " ", terminator:"")
}
print()
```

Output: 1 2 3 4

Answer (score 0):

```
let description = String(describing: yourVariable)
```

The `description` variable here would hold exactly the same output you would get in console by using `print()` function.
So you can replace anything in the output.
For example I use this code to print JSON in single line:

```
print(description.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: " "))
```