# What does it mean print(_:separator:terminator:)

Tags: swift

I don't understand the way Apple explain. What does it mean ":" between parameters?

It is used for assigning a function to a variable like this

```
func sum(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    return(a+b)
}

let addTwoNumbers = sum(a:b:)
addTwoNumbers(1, 2)
//prints 3
```

Comment: have you check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641736-print)

Comment: If you are refereing to the syntax it denotes a parameter "_:", "separator:", "terminator:" so 3 parameters, first one is anonymous the other two are named "separator" and "terminator". The reason you don't have to use the last two in your example is that they have default values.

Comment: See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30865283/11327526)

Comment: Please read the Functions chapter of the Swift book, specifically the [Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166) section.

Comment: I got the Answer below and understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 overloads of `print` (2 different functions with the same name) - [this one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541053-print) and [this one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641736-print).

If you just say `print`, it is ambiguous which overload you mean. Therefore, you also specify the parameter labels of the functions, so the first overload is called `print(_:separator:terminator:)` and the second is called `print(_:separator:terminator:to:)`.

Let's dissect `print(_:separator:terminator:)`. We can see that it has three parameter labels - `_`, `separator` and `terminator`. The `:` are just there to separate the labels. It is also the character you write after the label when you call the function:

```
print("hello", "world", separator: " ")
                                 ^
```

so it kind of makes sense.

Comment: It is for assigning a function to variable?

Comment: @John yes, and just referring to a function in general.