# Printing to console from Completion Handler in Swift Playground

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa-touch, swift-playground

I wanted to experiment with using NSURLSession to get RSS data, to see what that would look like. I wrote a chunk of code in a Playground, and when that didn't work I gutted the completion handler code and put in a print("hello, world") to verify the block was getting run.

```
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string:"http://apod.nasa.gov/apod.rss")!, completionHandler:
{(data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) in
    print("hello, world")
}
)!
task.resume()
```

In a Playground, nothing gets printed to the console. However I dropped this code into an Xcode project and it worked just fine. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print to console using swift playground?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003092/how-to-print-to-console-using-swift-playground)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well while trying to play with NSURLSession. First and foremost, you need to `import XCPlayground`, and call `XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()`. This will allow the code to be run asynchronously.

I can't tell you why *exactly* the print isn't working. All I know is, I was baffled by the same issue until I did a quick optional bind on the data (all the completion closure's parameters are optionals, mind you). For whatever reason, that works, and your print statement gets printed.

```
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string:"http://apod.nasa.gov/apod.rss")!, completionHandler:
    {(data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) in
        if let data = data
        {
            print("hello, world")
        }
    }
    )!
task.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

in Xcode 7.2 "XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely" is deprecated, now you can do the following:

```
import XCPlayground

//create instance of current playground page
let page = XCPlayground.XCPlaygroundPage
page.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

//create your completion handler function
func completionHandlerFunction(callBack: (message: String, error: ErrorType?) -> Void){
    callBack(message: "finish", error: nil)
}

//call the the completion handler function
completionHandlerFunction { (message, error) -> Void in
    print(message) //output on the right side will be "finish\n"

//perform .finishExecution() on current page when block is executed
    page.currentPage.finishExecution()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I was trying to print from inside a URL completionHandler:

```
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

...

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {

 ..

}).resume()
```