# Result sorting example Swift not showing up in Playground

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

I'm trying to work out an example which is provided on [developer.apple.com website](https://developer.apple.com/videos/enterprise/#56) 'Swift Playground'. I had to adapt it a little since swift 2 is, what looks like, different in handling 'inout' variables. In the example showed on the presentation 'inout' was not used in the function declaration. Anyway the result of 'data' is not showing in the Playground although the code doesn't show any compile errors.

```
import UIKit

var data = [16, 97, 13, 55, 95, 53, 18, 10, 79, 53, 79, 34, 50, 34, 0, 91, 94, 55, 6, 38, 7]

func exchange<T>(inout data:[T], i: Int, j: Int) {
    let temp = data[i]
    data[i] = data[j]
    data[j] = temp
}

func swapLeft<T: Comparable>(inout data: [T], index: Int) {
    for i in reverse(1...index) {
        if data[i] < data[i-1] {
            exchange(&data, i, i-1)
        }else {
            break
        }
    }
}

func isort<T: Comparable>(inout data: [T]) {
    for i in 1...data.count {
        swapLeft(&data,i)
    }
}
data //result [16, 97, 13, 55, 95, 53, 18, 10, 79, 53, 79, 34, 50, 34, 0, 91, 94, 55, 6, 38, 7]
isort(&data)
data //no result shown
```

**Screenshot**
[image: Screenshot Playground]

Comment: I think you got the correct answer now, but as an additional hint: You could have found the error yourself in the "Assistant Editor" (View -> Assistant Editor -> Show Assistant Editor). Also, if anything goes wrong in the Playground, I can only recommend to test the code in a compiled project (better error messages, better debugging possibilities).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't showing a result because it is crashing with *Array index out of range*.  Try this for `isort`:

```
func isort<T: Comparable>(inout data: [T]) {
    for i in 1..<data.count {
        swapLeft(&data,i)
    }
}
```

Comment: @OlivierdeJonge: Unless you are using an ancient Xcode version, it should be `1 ..< data.count`, exactly as in this answer.

Comment: The half-open range operator was changed from `..`  to `..<` on 7 July 2014 according to the Swift iBook. It was Xcode 6.0 beta 3.  Very ancient.

Comment: Thanks to you all my problem was a typo .. instead of ..<

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `println(data)`

Make sure your `Debug Area` is shown. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003092/how-to-print-to-console-using-swift-playground) for more info.

Comment: added screenshot, println doesn't help