# How can I print to console in Swift Playgrounds on iPad?

Tags: swift-playground

I would like to debug a method deep inside my "Sources" folder within a Swift Playground.

```swift
public func wannaDebugThis() {
    let x = 42
    let text = "Debug message with useful information: x = \(x)"
    print(text)
}
```

Within a macOS playground, the `print` output is shown in the debug area, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003092/how-to-print-to-console-using-swift-playground).

On iPad however, the `print` statement seems to be ignored. Even within Console.app on mac, I cannot find the desired output.

How do I write debug statements on iPad and where do I find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to write debug messages from the iPad to the console, `NSLog()` has to be used.

```swift
public func wannaDebugThis() {
    let x = 42
    let text = "Debug message with useful information: x = \(x)"
    NSLog(text)
}
```

The output of `NSLog()` can be found under the process named `ExecutionExtension` in Console.app on macOS. The output of `print` messages is only shown as `<private>`, which can be seen on attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

While I couldn‘t find a way to modify an Empty/Blank Playground to provide console in-/output. There is the „Answers“ template, that you can use for simple console interactions.

Another way is to use the „Interactions“ template, provided here: https://buildingrainbows.com/2018/03/13/print-to-the-console-in-swift-playgrounds-for-ipad/

Answer (score 2):

This feature has been added to Swift Playgrounds version 3.4 on iPad

[image: version History]

[image: Screenshot of Print]